# Haskell regular expression simplifier guards

Tags: regex, haskell

I am trying to further develop some Haskell code that was developed for simplifying regular expressions and I've run into a small problem. When I run the following command:

```
*Language.HaLex.RegExp> simplifyRegExp(Star (Or a Epsilon))
```

I get the output 'a'* and if I replace the a's with b's I get 'b'* like I should. The problem arises when I use Then. The following command:

```
*Language.HaLex.RegExp> simplifyRegExp(Then (Star a) (Star a))
```

works fine and produces 'a'* as expected but replacing a's with b's produced the following output:

```
*Language.HaLex.RegExp> simplifyRegExp(Then (Star b) (Star b))
'b'*'b'*
```

Although it is supposed to produce just 'b'*. Now if I change the variable name to b in the the line

```
simplifyRegExp (Then x y) | x' == Star a && y' == x' = y'
```

it works fine for b but not for any other letter. So my question is why it works fine in the Star part but not in the Then part?

I've added some of the important parts of the code below but feel free to ask for more if its not enough.

```
data RegExp sy  = Empty                          -- ^ Empty Language
            | Epsilon                            -- ^ Empty String
            | Literal   sy                       -- ^ Literals
            | Or        (RegExp sy) (RegExp sy)  -- ^ Disjuncion
            | Then      (RegExp sy) (RegExp sy)  -- ^ Sequence
            | Star      (RegExp sy)              -- ^ Repetition, possibly zero time
deriving (Read, Eq)

a = Literal 'a'
b = Literal 'b'
c = Literal 'c'

simplifyRegExp Empty        = Empty
simplifyRegExp Epsilon      = Epsilon
simplifyRegExp (Literal x)  = Literal x

simplifyRegExp (Star x)     = case x' of 
   Or a Epsilon -> Star (simplifyRegExp a)
where x' = simplifyRegExp x

simplifyRegExp (Then x y) | x' == Star a && y' == x' = y'
where x' =  simplifyRegExp x
      y' =  simplifyRegExp y
```

Answer (score 1):

You're having variable scoping issues.

In the `case` pattern match `Or a Epsilon` the `a` is a fresh variable bound locally to the right side of that case rule (i.e. `Star (simplifyRegExp a)`). Later, in the equation for `simplifyRegExp (Then x y)` you refer to `Star a` where the `a` is not *locally* bound but instead refers to the top-level definition

```
a  = Literal 'a'
```

That's almost certainly not the behavior you're intending as the simplification of a regular expression goes over its structure and ignores the actual choice of literals.

Comment: Is there a way to make it locally bound because I really want to keep the top-level definition for a? I changed the Then x y guard to x' == Star (simplifyRegExp a) && y' == x' = y' but the same problem is still there?

Comment: What would it be locally bound *to*? There's no `a` variable in your pattern match for instance.

Comment: If you merely want to check that it's the `Star` of *something* then I suggest you write another function `isStar :: RegExp -> Bool`.